# Swift 3.0 conversion - contains(_:) in Collection

Tags: collections, swift3, contains

I am trying to convert a project from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3.

Here is some issue with `contains(_:)` from `Collection`:

```
extension Collection {
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Iterator.Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

The error is `Missing argument label 'where:' in call`

I added `where:`, but now, another error appears:

`Cannot convert value of type 'Self.Index' to expected argument type '(_) throws -> Bool'`

From Swift 3.0 language guide it seems that it should work without errors:

```
if favoriteGenres.contains("Funk") {
    print("I get up on the good foot.")
} else {
    print("It's too funky in here.")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 3, the `indices` property of `Collection` is not a `Collection`, but just an `IndexableBase` & `Sequence`. Which has no `contains(_:)` method, but only `contains(where:)` method.

(From the generated header.)

> ```
> associatedtype Indices : IndexableBase, Sequence = DefaultIndices<Self>
>
> public var indices: Self.Indices { get }
> ```

You may need to write something like this:

```
extension Collection {
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Iterator.Element? {
        return (startIndex..<endIndex).contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

Or else you can invoke `contains(_:)` method for `Sequence where Iterator.Element : Equatable`, with adding some constraints:

```
extension Collection
where Indices.Iterator.Element: Equatable, Index == Indices.Iterator.Element
{
    subscript (safe index: Indices.Iterator.Element) -> Iterator.Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

Both work for simple Arrays:

```
let arr = [1,2,3]
print(arr[safe: 3]) //->nil
print(arr[safe: 2]) //->Optional(3)
```

But I'm not sure which is the safer generally.